# How to change the Jquery form submit function into AngularJS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a JQuery function that will trigger if I hit the update button on the form. Which is working. I am planning to change it to Angular JS directive. 
Not sure what to do, I am very very new to Angular JS.

I have tried to code it in Angular JS way, but I am not sure how to pass the whole form data to the function like I did with JQuery.

This is the html file,

form.HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" id="billingInfoForm" name="billingInfoForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="firstName">First Name </label>
      <input type="text" data-recurly="first_name" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName"
        ng-model="team.team_name">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="lastName">Last Name </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" data-recurly="last_name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="address1">Address</label>
      <input type="text" data-recurly="address1" class="form-control" id="address1" name="address1"
        ng-model="team.team_address.address1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" data-recurly="city"
        ng-model="team.team_address.city">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="state">State <span class="required"></span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" data-recurly="state"
        ng-model="team.team_address.region">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="postal_code">Zipcode</label>
      <input type="text" data-recurly="postal_code" class="form-control" id="postal_code"
        name="postal_code" ng-model="team.team_address.postcode">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" data-recurly="country" class="form-control" id="country" name="country"
        ng-model="team.team_address.country">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="margin-left-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

This is the JQuery function which is working.
jQueryController.js

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = this;
  recurly.token(form, function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      somefunction();
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

This is the Angular JS way I am trying but not working:
angularController.js:

```
$scope.update = function(event){
  //event.preventDefault();
  var form = 'billingInfoForm';
  recurly.token(form, function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      somefunction();
      form.submit();
    }
  });
}
```

Please let me know which part I did wrong. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the element of the form, not a string:

```
$scope.update = function(event){
  //event.preventDefault();
  ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶m̶ ̶=̶ ̶'̶b̶i̶l̶l̶i̶n̶g̶I̶n̶f̶o̶F̶o̶r̶m̶'̶;̶
  var formEl = document.getElementById('billingInfoForm');
  var form = angular.element(formEl);
  recurly.token(form, function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      somefunction();
      form.submit();
    }
  });
}
```